# Can we please quit ragging on the posters who want to support IE6?

Tags: discussion, internet-explorer

I hoping to gauge the feeling of the community with this question.  My apologies that it seems a bit "ranty".

If a post is about a problem which only occurs in Internet Explorer 6, there are sometimes comments or answers along the lines of "don't support IE6".  These comments/answers aren't **helpful**; they are noise, distracting from solving the problem that the poster is asking about.

If an SO user doesn't want to hear about or solve problems with IE6, that's fine, they don't have to.  They could just add "internet-explorer-6" to their ignored tags, instead of ragging on those unfortunate folks who, for business reasons, are trying to support IE6.

Comment: Gotta say, you should really stop supporting IE6 supporters. I understand you may have a valid business case for needing to support the supporters, but so long as supporters continue to support the supporters, support will drag on and we'll *all* suffer.

Comment: If a large group of cranky web developers were enough to put the final nails in IE6's coffin, it would *already* be 6 feet underground.

Comment: @Shog9 - You gotta stop hating the IE6 supporters supporters. We just can't get anything done here without all the supporters supporters fighting against the supporters non-supporters, and the supporters non-supporters supporters.

Comment: @Rob: I fully support your unsupportive attitude toward my unsupportive attitude toward the supportive attitude of the IE6 supporter supporters.

Comment: @Shog9 - Since my comment 9 minutes ago, I've unfortunately lost track of what I currently support. I therefore rescind my support for or against supporters and/or non-supporters of supporters, non-supporters, athletic supporters, sports, sporks, or pork, supporting or not supporting the support or non-support of IE6.

Comment: I'm [more than a little](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898244/ie6-added-a-large-left-offset-to-my-element#comment-5451842) sick of this myself, and have been thinking about aggressively flagging them as useless, but it's tiring when its an actual culture. It's one thing to answer the question *and* maybe suggest possible reasons for dropping/degrading IE6, but I don't see why the "just drop it" people even bother typing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you flag them as noise? It's unlikely the people doing that are actually following meta to see this post. If enough people flag the comment as noise it'll be deleted automatically

Comment: I could do so.  I haven't in the past because it feels like too strong of an admonishment since noise, spam, and offensive are all grouped in the same control.

Comment: @KatieK: yeah, a lot of folks have that hang-up. But keep in mind, there's really no *penalty* for having a comment flag-deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I think a comment pointing out that IE6 could just not be supported is useful, unless the poster specifically mentioned that not supporting IE6 is not a choice.

Just like other cases where a poster might say I am having trouble using X to do ABC.  Sometimes the best suggestion is don't use X instead use Y.  Unless there is some other requirement that forces the use of X.

I could understand cases where multiple comments or persistent comments after the OP says "I have to support IE6", could be noise and should be flagged as such as Michael mentioned.